# Git clone over HTTP

Tags: git, http, repository, clone

I am interested in step by step workflow that a Git client does when you execute `clone` command over HTTP protocol.

Let's say your Git repository is located here `http://gitserver.com/gitrepo`.

When you do Git clone over HTTP protocol `git clone http://gitserver.com/gitrepo`, client accesses these URLs:

```
GET  http://gitserver.com/gitrepo/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
POST http://gitserver.com/gitrepo/git-upload-pack
```

Why does it do those requests? What does it do next? How does it get a full list of files in repository?

Comment: Have you tried wireshark? You will be able to monitor all communication between client and server. Since its HTTP, it should be all clear text.

Answer (score 1):

Old versions of git did not support the "*Smart HTTP protocol*" (like the ones used in `ssh` and `git`).  So, sending a `GET` and then a `POST` (depending of the results of `GET`) is an elegant way to keep support for both, old and new one.  As [Git SCM chapter "Smart HTTP Transport"](http://www.git-scm.com/2010/03/04/smart-http.html) states:

> The new clients will now send a request with an extra GET parameter
>   that older servers will simply ignore, but servers running the smart
>   CGI will recognize and switch modes to a multi-POST mode that is
>   similar to the conversation that happens over the git protocol. Once
>   this series of POSTs is complete, the server knows what objects the
>   client needs and can build a custom packfile and stream it back.

In addition, you can find the dumb and smart protocols described in detail in [Pro-Git book, chapter 9, section "*Transfer Protocol*"](https://github.com/progit/progit/blob/master/en/09-git-internals/01-chapter9.markdown#transfer-protocols).